# Run pyd compiled with python2.6 on python2.7

Tags: python, pyd

I have a python pyd module that has been compiled with python26.dll (its 'msparser' by matrixscience, a library to interface with some mass spectrometry data formats).  It is possible to use this pyd module on windows with activestate python 2.7.  However, on a generic install it throws the ImportError: DLL load failed... because python26.dll is missing.

So, is there any advice for importing a pyd compiled with an earlier version of python on a later version of python?  Activestate is achieving this somehow so I guess it has to be possible.

Comment: Can you show where  Activestate is achieving this?

Comment: I have an activestate installation with it working.  Here's the online documentation as well for it:http://www.matrixscience.com/parser_support.html (Under Windows, ActivePython version 2.6 or 2.7 (32 or 64 bit) must be installed. Under Unix, Python 2.6 or 2.7, (32 or 64 bit) must be installed.).  I basically want to know how to get the same results activestate achieves with vanilla python.

Comment: How is mAscot installed (I can't see as it requires registration) Also the wording reads to me that matrix have only tested with those versions of python not that it won't work in generic python

Comment: Mascot is something entirely different (its a licensed software, and you won't be installing it, the licenses are in the 10s of thousands).  Msparser just parses the output.  Using a vanilla/enthought python distribution, upon improrting msparser I get the DLL error.  Using dependency walker on _msparser.pyd, I see it requires python26.dll.  So it won't work with generic python, I want to know how activepython is different so it magically works there but not with the generic python.

Comment: I think that you get the same issue with ActiveState - the pyd needs to be compiled for each version of python. Anyway your issue is with Msparser and how it is compiled

Comment: Thanks...let's hope I can convince them to compile another version.  My program depends on msparser and I'd hate to require anyone to use python26 to open this format.